# Debugging Unit Tests in MonoDevelop 3

Tags: mono, nunit, monodevelop

I'm getting an exception:

Null Ref >  Stack Trace (System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke( {yadda yadda} )

when I try to debug unit tests in MonoDevelop.  I'm running MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2 on Lubuntu installed from the standard repo.  I have referenced the mono versions of nunit (I'm not sure why there are standard and mono versions either?).

I have been able to debug unit tests using older versions on MonoDevelop.  Example solution here:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30149716/DebugUnitTest.zip

I have downloaded the above and successfully debugged in VS (having change the unit refs of course)

================ EDIT ================

I filed a bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8442

Comment: report a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Good idea..done https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8442

Comment: nice; you should also try MonoDevelop's master branch in case it's already fixed there

Comment: Works here using current master that identifies itself as 3.0.5, using the bundled nunit 2.6.0.

Comment: Cool..sounds like I need to roll my sleeves up a build it locally..can anyone post a good guide for doing so?  Thanks